# Automatically increment sheet reference when dragging formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, excel-indirect

I have a formula with the following syntax:

```
=SheetName!E10
```

and need some way to drag the formula and change just the sheet name as it moves to the right. So the `E10` part needs to stay the same with the sheet number incrementing as I drag the formula. We have many rows and columns to do and this would definitely speed us up.

Is this possible?

So the result would look like this:

```
=Sheet1!E10    =Sheet2!E10    =Sheet3!E10
```

This is the result:

[image: SO26599056 question example]

from applying this formula:

```
=INDIRECT("mo"&COLUMN()+0&"!B4")
```

Comment: By "format" do you mean "formula"? You should look up the `INDIRECT` function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please try:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet"&COLUMN()+x&"!E10")
```

where `x` is the offset to return the appropriate number ( Column()+x ) for wherever you choose to place the formula.

*Edit* to match subsequent details from the image (where `5` may be in ColumnB) and a comment, perhaps should be:

```
=INDIRECT("mo"&COLUMN()-1&"!E10")
```

Comment: It drags the first 2 columns correctly, I'll show the screen shot.

Comment: The sheet names are on the pic.